# Clients authentication and user authentication with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0

I am working on api, where I have the following models.

```
Merchant -> hasMany -> Shops
Shop -> hasMany -> Customers
```

Each merchant will have api tokens in order to connect his apps with the api, but also i want to provide authentication for the customers.

I know that I can achieve the clients (Merchant) authentication on api with the laravel passport, but what about the customers authentication?

Comment: Is there a reason why you would not use the same type of authentication for customers?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use different authentication then you can create custom Provider and custom Guard in auth.php

Add Guard For  Customer in auth.php

```
 'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users'
        // 'hash' => false,
    ],

    // Guard For Customer 

     'custome_api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'customers'
    ],
],
```

Here Customers Provider Added for customer in auth.api

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],

     'customers' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
       'model' => App\Models\Customer::class,
    ],
],
```